# Why do STM32 gcc linker scripts automatically discard all input sections from these standard libraries: libc.a, libm.a, libgcc.a?

Tags: c, linker, stm32, ld, binutils

From the bottom of any auto-generated STM32CubeMx-generated linker script:

```
/* Remove information from the standard libraries */
/DISCARD/ :
{
  libc.a ( * )
  libm.a ( * )
  libgcc.a ( * )
}
```

From the GNU Binutils ld (linker script) manual, [3.6.7 Output Section Discarding](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.32/ld/Output-Section-Discarding.html#Output-Section-Discarding):

> The special output section name ‘/DISCARD/’ may be used to discard input sections. Any input sections which are assigned to an output section named ‘/DISCARD/’ are not included in the output file.

What do these 3 input object files contain, and why do we discard everything (all input sections) from them?

### Other STM32 linker script topics of interest:

1. [Is accessing the "value" of a linker script variable undefined behavior in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622174/is-accessing-the-value-of-a-linker-script-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c)
2. [How to get value of variable defined in ld linker script from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561217/how-to-get-value-of-variable-defined-in-ld-linker-script-from-c/54728097#54728097)

Comment: I think to get an answer for this, someone needs to go ask ST the company and/or ARM the company directly, and report back.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like in this example, `/DISCARD/` removes any other sections, that are not explicitly defined by script. For example, since `*(.text)`, `*(.data)`, `*(.bss)`, `*(.init_array)` etc, has been defined earlier in the script, they get into the ELF. But **libc**, **libm** or **libgcc** could contain unnecessary sections for firmware (e.g. .foo, .bar, .debug ...), so /DISCARD/ just wipes them out, but NOT all sections!