# Sybolys from Linker Script imported wrong to C code

Tags: c, linker-scripts

I'm currently facing a strange issue.

My Linker script declares the heap size:

```
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x1F000;    /* required amount of heap  */
```

In my C File i'm including this value by declaring it extern (I'm not doing anything else)

```
extern size_t _Min_Heap_Size;           ///< Heap Size
```

However my C program asserts here

```
Assert(_Min_Heap_Size == 0x1F000u);
```

And indeed, when viewing _Min_Heap_Size which the debugger it shows me a really unplausible value:
_Min_Heap_Size  = 0x47984611.

I checked the output map

```
__heap_end__        |2002f31c|   B  |            NOTYPE|        |     |._user_heap_stack
__heap_start__      |2001031c|   B  |            NOTYPE|        |     |._user_heap_stack
```

2002f31c - 2001031c = 0x1F000 => this is the size I'm expecting.

So the symbols are linked correctly, I'm simply reading the wrong value.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You need to use the address of the symbol which is its value. Maybe look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622174/is-accessing-the-value-of-a-linker-script-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c

Comment: thx that did really help. Using the Address of these symbols worked fine :)