# Cannot write to variable defined in LD linker script when compiling with -Os option

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm

I am writing a program to run bare metal. I am trying to write to a variable from a custom linker script. The code runs perfectly when compiled with -O0 options but not as expected when compiled with -Os option.

The code I used is as follows.

main.c:

```
#define TTB_BASE (&Image$$TTB)
extern unsigned int Image$$TTB;

int main ()
{
    *TTB_BASE = 56326;

    unsigned int *ttb=TTB_BASE+16;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
    {
        *ttb++ = 1;
    }
    *(volatile unsigned int*)(0x00100000) = *TTB_BASE;
}
```

When compiled with -Os option, the code **TTB_BASE = 56326;* is seems to be optimized out and the value is not stored to the address TTB_BASE.

The linker script used:

ARMCA7.ld

```
ENTRY(main)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x00160000;
    .text : { *(.text*) }
    .data : { *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d*) }
    .bss (NOLOAD) : {
        . = ALIGN(16);
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(COMMON)
    }
    . = 0x00170000;
    .ttb :
    {
        Image$$TTB = .;
    }
}
```

Compiling statement:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a7 -Os -std=gnu99 -c -o main.o main.c
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a7 -Os -T ARMCA7.ld -nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,"main.map" -o main.elf main.o
```

Disassembly got:

```
Address : Opcode         Statement
-------   ------         ---------
 8                        unsigned int *ttb=TTB_BASE+16;
                      main:
00160000: 24 30 9f e5   ldr     r3, [pc, #36]   ; 0x16002c <main+44>
12                            *ttb++ = 1;
00160004: 01 10 a0 e3   mov     r1, #1
00160008: 20 20 83 e2   add     r2, r3, #32
0016000c: 04 10 83 e4   str     r1, [r3], #4
10                        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
00160010: 02 00 53 e1   cmp     r3, r2
00160014: fc ff ff 1a   bne     0x16000c <main+12>
14                        *(volatile unsigned int*)(0x00100000) = *TTB_BASE;
00160018: 60 20 13 e5   ldr     r2, [r3, #-96]  ; 0xffffffa0
0016001c: 01 36 a0 e3   mov     r3, #1048576    ; 0x100000
15                    }
00160020: 00 00 a0 e3   mov     r0, #0
14                        *(volatile unsigned int*)(0x00100000) = *TTB_BASE;
00160024: 00 20 83 e5   str     r2, [r3]
15                    }
00160028: 1e ff 2f e1   bx      lr
0016002c: 40 00 17 00   andseq  r0, r7, r0, asr #32
```

It can be seen that nothing is written to the address TTB_BASE which is 0x00170000 defined in the linker script, and the value written to address 0x00100000 is wrong.

Is there some bug in the code or linker script?

**Note:**

If I change the first two lines of *main.c* to the following code,

```
#define TTB_BASE (Image$$TTB)
extern unsigned int Image$$TTB[];
```

The code can be correctly compiled and the address TTB_BASE is written correctly. However, as I seen from [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561217/how-to-get-value-of-variable-defined-in-ld-linker-script-from-c), both approach should be correct.

gcc version used:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (Arm GNU Toolchain 11.3.Rel1) 11.3.1 20220712
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I also test the code with arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe 10.3.1 20210621 (release) and got the same problem.

Comment: Did you try to add `volatile` to your variables? Perhaps the optimizer sees the assignment as useless because the code never uses the stored value.

Comment: @thebusybee `volatile` also works. But is this the **correct** way for fixing this problem?

Comment: @thebusybee When I add `*(volatile unsigned int*)(0x00100000) = *TTB_BASE;` before end of `main` to use the value of TTB_BASE, I still got the same problem, and the value written to address 0x00100000 is wrong.

Comment: `Image$$TTB` is only a symbol, not a variable. It does not contain any data, and has only the address. 

If you place other sections after this one you will write over those sections. It is not a correct way of using linker scripts.

Comment: @0___________ No, `Image$$TTB` is clearly a global variable to the compiler. Its location is allocated in the linker script, but it could be defined in a separate module.

Comment: @FeihuLiu Would you mind to [edit] your question and add the additional experimental sources you tried, including the effects you see? -- Optimally you provide links to the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/). You don't need the linker script, because the compiled object code should suffice to see the result.

Comment: @thebusybee it is a symbol only and it has an address only. I work with linker scripts all the time as it is part of my daytime job. It is not a **variable** and there is no real object behind it.

Comment: @thebusybee Please refer to [link](https://godbolt.org/z/WY1rW8hGs)

Comment: @0___________ Ah yes, the linker script does not provide space.

Comment: I test some gcc versions including x86, x86-64, arm, and found that all tested versions have such problem. And it is not related to linker script. The problem exists for any external variables.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. Very strange, and if you comment anything but the assignment, it appears. Perhaps you found a bug. -- Oh well. However, since I think my answer has some value, I'll keep it. Unfortunately I have some work to do now.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for your help. It would be better for me to post a more general question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the question posted is related to **variables references** other than **linker script**. Please refer to this [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624548/does-external-variables-always-need-to-be-volatile-when-complied-with-gcc) for further discussion.

For a conslusion, the real reason why the code does not work is as follows. `&Image$$TTB+16` is *[Undefined Behavior in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/undefined-behavior-c-cpp/)*.

That is, the following declaration will be needed if you want to change the address regions defined in linker script file.

```
extern unsigned int Image$$TTB[];
```

The following is another example code that has the same bug. Note that it should be compiled with -O1 or above. You can try it [at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9EP5aWqnf).

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int var;
volatile unsigned int valid_address[1024];
int main ()
{
    var = 56326;
    unsigned int *ttb=&var;
    ttb += 16;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
    {
        *ttb++ = 1;
    }
    valid_address[0] = var;
    printf("Value is: %d", valid_address[0]);
}
```

If you execute this code, you might get the following output:

```
Value is: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your external variable has no *side effects* visible to the compiler, and as such it is allowed to optimize the assignment out.

The standard compliant way to avoid this is to add the qualifier `volatile`. It tells the compiler that this variable has side effects. Therefore it cannot optimize the assignment out.

```c
extern volatile unsigned int Image$$TTB;
```

You need this qualifier also, if you have multiple threads like interrupt service routines, which share variables with each other or the main thread.

---

Addition:

As others pointed out in comments, there is an error in the linker script. You don't reserve space for the variable.

Comment: It seems that even if *side effects* are available, the problem still exists. Please refer to my **update**.

Comment: @FeihuLiu: In your update, you did not add `volatile` where it is needed, in `extern volatile unsigned int Image$$TTB;`. It is the write to `image$$TTB` that was being omitted, and therefore it is `image$$TTB` that needs to be `volatile`. (And then pointers to it also need to include `volatile`, so that is needed as well.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I know how to make it work, but I'm curious why the updated code does not work.

Comment: @FeihuLiu: What is the value you observe stored in location 0x00100000 by the updated code? You did not show enough assembly to tell that, as it is stored from `r2`, which is loaded from `[r3, #-96]` when `r3` is pointing to 0x16002c + 32, so `[r3, #-96]` is at 0x15ffec, which you did not show.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In the updated code, Image$$TTB was set to 0x00170000 because the previous is not suitable for my debug environment. When 0x00100000 is stored, r3 is pointing to 0x170040 + 32. The statement `ldr     r3, [pc, #36]` means to get the content stored in the memory address [pc+36]. Please refer to my [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624548/does-external-variables-always-need-to-be-volatile-when-complied-with-gcc) for a clearer statement of the question.